# "A hard disk may be failing" , but no additional info via gdu-notification-deamon (suggestions?)

Tags: 10.04, hardware

Got this message after logging in:

```
A hard disk may be failing 
One or more hard disk report health problems.
Click the icon to get more information.
```

On WUBI and 10.04, there was no icon to click, and clicking on made the message go away.

After rebooting, the message did not display again.

I've got everything on all my hard drives in duplicate, so not super worried about a disk failure, though I am wondering why the message had no info on which disk it thought had problems. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The not showing more information is a bug but there's still a core issue of a failing disk that you need to address immediately.

Coincidentally, there was a thread on this yesterday that I suggest you read over: [Do I need to replace my hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14978/do-i-need-to-replace-my-hard-disk/15027#15027)

Comment: Your right, but  turns out this is a drive that's already dead... :-) ...meaning I forgot it's even in the case, Windows stop seeing it a long time ago. So, guess +1 for Linux seeing a dead drive. Found the "icon" on the top right desktop navigation bar, but using the directions and info you gave in the other answer was the info I was looking for, thanks. Selecting you as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known bug: **Bug #469499** [Usability issue in "hard disk failing" dialog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/469499).   
It's good that you have a backup ready.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, figured that was just bad interface design, but Oli answered the question about where the addition info was, thanks for the additional info though, since I am interested in how the system design of Ubuntu works; meaning the GUI, and community feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded to UNR 10.04 and have started getting this error but can't find any more information.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but I actually have no 'hard disk' as such ... my computer is an eee 701 and I believe the storage is flash.  Disk Utility reports it as a hard disk but I can't see any relevant additional information in there.  So I'm not sure if my storage is failing or the error report is in error.

Michael

Comment: @Micchael: I'd suggest just posting your issue as a different question, since it does appear to be something else -- do try to give as much info as possible, including the last version that you were using without the error. Cheers, and Happy New Year!