# Hard disk makes weird noises during installation

Tags: installation, hardware, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to replace my hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14978/do-i-need-to-replace-my-hard-disk)

I got the same problem - installing ubuntu. My hard disk is also emitting certain weird noise. What other option do i have rather then replacing my HDD? should i try installing ubuntu through USB. If yes how exactly should i go about with it?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Could you detail what kind of issues you had while installing Ubuntu ? Did the install process stop at some point with some error message ?

Comment: if the HDD is making noises then it ´s most likely it will eventually die

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you think you may have hardware issues with your HDD, you should check it's [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status. Boot your computer with an Ubuntu LiveCD and check your drive status through Disk Utility (System -> Administration menu).
See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14978/do-i-need-to-replace-my-hard-disk/15027#15027) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: From your question I would assume the hard drive has never made any 'weird noise' prior to the installation of Ubuntu - don't panic Ubuntu is probably not the cause...

All hard drives have an infinite life and yours is more than likely past it's 50% mark, as Maxime has already posted check it's SMART status and then take action...

Comment: Didn't you meant a *finite* life ?