# SMART status:-- DISK FAILURE IS IMMINENT

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I want to run the check file system tool, but for that I need to unmount the volume, I have just one partition, should I go ahead with unmount and repair. I am new to Ubuntu, so please help.(Image)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda` , please consider a Backup plan as soon as possible . I guess Checking and correcting File system won't help , since it is Hardware related, try to **invest** your time in Backing Up important data.

Comment: See if this can help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159368/what-should-i-do-when-hard-disk-failure-is-imminent/159390#159390

Comment: This is a hardware problem with the disk, not the filesystem, so I don't think it can be repaired by any operating system.  Modern hard disk drives can remap bad sectors on their own, but in this case, the only safe thing to do is to replace the drive as soon as possible, while you can still recover data.

Comment: I'll add to Martys comment, I think because it is physical, the problem will only get worse and you will lose data.

Comment: Also **Stop using the drive for anything other than data backup**.

Comment: Click on the SMART DATA button and put the details in your question, rather than the partition screen.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem which happened to me last year. When it says `"Disk failure is IMMINENT"`, it really means that. Pull whatever data you value off of that, because it won't be long before it fails completely, wiping out what's on it. `(Where "Won't be long can range from a day to about a week in my experience")`

This is a hardware issue. The disk is physically failing. If it's new enough, check about sending it in under warranty. There isn't any repairing it.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from contacting your disk's manufacturer, check my answer on  [What to do if Disk Utility shows bad sectors pending in SMART?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159829/what-to-do-if-disk-utility-shows-bad-sectors-pending-in-smart?rq=1) as a last solution.

Won't save you the trouble to buy a new drive, or give you piece of mind about your data in this one, but could keep your disk away from the trash can for a while...