# Bad Sectors on Lubuntu?

Tags: disk, drive

I  have a Dell Inspiron network which has both Windows and Lubuntu installed.

When I check the disk with Lubuntu, it says "disk ok 1497 bad sectors". However, when I check the disk in Windows it doesn't report any issues. Is Windows only checking its own partition? If so, why does Lubuntu partition have so many errors but the Windows partition has none?

Did Lubuntu cause these?

Comment: Yes, windows only checks its partition.  Your disk is failing and needs replaced.

Comment: Have you checked the hard drive's (if that's what you're using) SMART info & tests? What's telling you there's bad sectors now, `fsck`?

Answer (score 0):

Please,

*Please,*

**Please,**

### Please!

## Make a system backup now!

***Your hard drive is in imminent danger of failing any minute!***

Please follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/159386/344926) *right now!*

***If you do not have a hard disk to back-up to:***

**Do not** turn off your computer!  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following command:

```
sudo parted --list
```

then copy-paste the output of that command to any word processor or text editor, print it off, go to a store and show them the print and ask to buy an "external USB hard disk than can contain this data".

Please?  Pretty please???

Comment: And after you've followed the instructions above, also have a look at [what's a good backup strategy for 1 PC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc). You're probably user type 3...

Comment: So was it a bad install since only the partition with lubuntu is failing?

Comment: If you haven't yet made a back-up of Windows too, please do so as I'm afraid your entire hard drive is failing... :(

Comment: @david-americorojas-coppa:  As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**