# Backup without free space in not recognized partition

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, clone

I am trying to make a complete backup of an HDD partition to `/dev/sdd` (**100gb**), but I want to only take the contained data (**50gb**).

**I can't access** the internal data in the HDD for putting `zeros` with `dd` because Linux will not recognize it. Neither can I see the partition (but I know that only one partition exists).

**The objective is:** to take data (50gb) **without free space** and take  the tables and partition "form" because I want to clone it onto other HDD with a **limit of 70GB**, then it should be recognized by Xbox console

**About my question:** I've search in multiple forums but always uses the classic methods for cloning and surely I need advanced options for solved it

**Add about CLONEZILLA:** The clonezilla not works for me, because he can't recognized partitions of my hdd (maybe reason why is a xbox360 partition), therefore only can clone all partition..

How could I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Clonezilla is the solution which does exactly what you want to achieve, backing up the used data space of partitions. Download [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) and create a bootable DVD or USB media from the ISO file. Boot from the media and clone the content of the disk or a partition. I have created two presentations explaining how to do this : [Create a partition backup with Clonezilla](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13-GCZyxH51pWD-aMzmD-QNpDr7U28ZqTmEB-Iy3wizM/edit#slide=id.p) and [Restore a partition backup with Clonezilla](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1mSc1BAJBIQMbKKzI2OjG9tWEt7p7GeGY50InYgWzgVQ/edit#slide=id.p). Clonezilla lets you clone the used space of complete disks or of single partitions very reliably.

Comment: Are you sure bro? I have clonezilla in my usb, I go into try it, thank you!!

Comment: @Milor123 : Yes, I am very sure ... I am using Clonezilla for years, a swiss army knife, it never let me down. For the part of cloning the content of a source disk to a smaller destination disk ... this might be useful -> http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/119_larger_to_smaller_disk_restore_clone.faq#119_larger_to_smaller_disk_restore_clone.faq ! :)

Comment: Dude its not work for my, the clonezilla cant detect the partition of hdd (maybe because is a xbox360 partition), therefore only could clone all entire disk...