# Hard Drive Load Cycle Count

Tags: smart

Does the load cycle count shown below, using SMART, show the total count of the hard drives lifetime? What is the maximum count?

Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   081   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       39246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your drive firmware is operating correctly, you have had 39246 load cycles for the lifetime of the disk.

I've read that 500,000 to 600,000 is fine for most drives, but I believe this is defined by the manufacturer. You should go to the manufacturer's website for more information.

It's a good idea to track how many sectors are being remapped. If these increase rapidly it's time to think about replacing the hard drive. `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`, for example, will also list the most recent I/O errors for drive /dev/sda.

It's always time to think about how adequate your data backups are.

You can use `palimpsest` to get an overall summary of how your drives are doing. See also [How Do I interpret HDD S.M.A.R.T Results?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20393/how-do-i-interpret-hdd-s-m-a-r-t-results?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful indeed! I'll check out those links you provided.