# Laptop slowing down

Tags: 14.04, laptop

A few months ago, I installed 14.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire 5250. Ubuntu ran great. Slowly but surely, it is slowing down more and more. I don'tknow what the cause of this could be. I haven't installed any applications in the last 3 months, but boot time, and response time is very laggy. Is there anyway to check why?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried opening up System Monitor and looking at what resources are being used up? Look for things like swap use and CPU use over 50%.

Comment: It might also be worth it to perform a [SMART test](http://askubuntu.com/a/528077/205638) on your hard drive and see if you get any [bad results](http://askubuntu.com/a/20439/205638).