# Is my HDD going to kick the bucket?

Tags: hard-drive

My kubuntu 18.04 sometimes behaves like there is no space left on HDD (can't update, errors popping up when open any application, etc.)
despite I am using only around 30Gb of a 320Gb drive. After hard reset the machine boots into BusyBox where I have to do 'fsck' and fix multiple errors in order to be able to boot again. After that everything is normal for few months and then it happens again.

Here is the results of short and long tests using smartmontools:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.19.1-041901-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2177         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2176         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0
```

### -

Do you think she is going to kick the bucket soon? 2177 hours is just 90 days if it is on 24/7.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `df -h` and `df -i`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I interpret HDD S.M.A.R.T Results?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20393/how-do-i-interpret-hdd-s-m-a-r-t-results)