# Various issues with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: command-line, home-directory, logo

I have some difficulties with my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and I am using Lenovo-G580. The problems are as follow:

1. When I want to open the home directory, it takes a long time (about 1-2 min) to show the directories inside it
2. Terminal could not memorize the commands I mean when I restart it, I could not see previous commands by up/down keys
3. In some cases it is stuck in the logo page then I have to restart it manually with the power key, because other keys do not work and in the other cases it remains in a black page with this error: dev/sda2
4. Some icons on desktop are missing
5. I could not change the light intensity of the screen

Generally I am not sure if all these issues are related to Ubuntu but I think that it could be a good start point to address them. And thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: That's... quite a few issues. Do these issues still happen if you use Ubuntu from a Live USB? I explain how to do that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384358/1438484)

Comment: It should not be that slow. But I have newer system and use Kubuntu which is a middle weight system. Older system may need lightweight flavor. Slow HDD does not help your system. Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Review your logs. Your system might already be telling you exactly what the problems are. Logs often contain rich deposits of troubleshooting information.