# Dell XPS 9320 and Ubuntu 22.04 Freezes

Tags: 22.04, dell, freeze, xps

I bought Dell XPS Plus 9320 last year September with only Ubuntu 22.04 installed. Recently the laptop has been freezing, making it hard to work. I talked with Dell Tech support and did some few tests: hard shutdown, updating the BIOS and checking the system for any hardware issues, we found none. They referred me to this page to find what could be happening. The laptop freezes time and again, in a space of a few minutes, both online and offline (so it is not a problem with internet connection).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose my issue, when I'm not sure if it is a hardware or software issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384357/how-do-i-diagnose-my-issue-when-im-not-sure-if-it-is-a-hardware-or-software-is)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. My Dell XPS 15 9520 freezes randomly when I show some video in youtube on local video player. It started with kernel update to 5.19.0-40. On 5.19.0-38 everything work normal. 5.19.0-41 has the same problem

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1295331)

Comment: Now it is freezing on every kernel. Maybe it's a BIOS update problem