# Ubuntu Distro Freezes or suddendly shutdown

Tags: 22.04, dell, shutdown, freeze

My laptop boots fine without any error or problem. But Sometimes like after using it for 30 minutes it freezes. Nothing works except pressing the power button for force shutdown.
I also observe that It unexpectedly shut down.

Laptop Model:
Dell Latitude 7490 8th gen i7
I tried to figure out this problem by running dell pre-boot Diagnostic test
I got the error
4306.30 One or more errors detected.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product or release details, are we to guess?  Please provide this detail, as without it we're very limited with what we can provide as for advice, and can't know what options are available for you.  You also should *never* need to use the power button, does SysRq commands not allow you to reboot/shutdown cleanly?  (they'll work even on a stuck/dead GUI/UI) as that's useful detail too.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS version

Comment: Please add that detail to your question, including if you're asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, Ubuntu 22.04 Server etc... ie. please provide clear & as complete detail as possible.  (*this is a Q&A site & not a forum, comments are just comments, all answers will be to details in your question, with comments intended for us to ask the OP or Original Poster question, replies are by amendments/additional details in the question where by comments get deleted*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose my issue, when I'm not sure if it is a hardware or software issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384357/how-do-i-diagnose-my-issue-when-im-not-sure-if-it-is-a-hardware-or-software-is)