# At grub rescue> prompt but the keyboard is not responding although it's connected

Tags: grubrescue, troubleshooting

I'm running Ubuntu 20 or 21. I had rebooted because stupid Firefox froze. Honestly I do not know what message was, duh did not record it.  I rebooted and received a message of chassis intrusion followed by this error message: `re:'...normal.mode' not found , entering rescue mode, grub rescue>`. I shut down the computer, found a dead giant moth inside and removed it.

Don't ask, but now I have a wonky system. To restart I must reposition the memory chip, restart and cross my fingers. It booted up to the same message. It's late night now. I shut down the computer again and restarted it an hour ago.

That's when I found your website on my Android, asked for assistance, and discovered that the keys were still not responding. I remember that the light was on. I did a reboot, but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose my issue, when I'm not sure if it is a hardware or software issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384357/how-do-i-diagnose-my-issue-when-im-not-sure-if-it-is-a-hardware-or-software-is) The accepted answer to this question is relevant to your question. Boot from the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu.

Comment: No. But iinteresting

Comment: We need more information than just grub rescue> to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I added an edit/update. Issue resolved by one final shut down and reboot but do not know why.

Comment: It seems like the problem was caused by some kind of bug.

Comment: Kinda funny idea. I e. A bug. I had initually received a chassis intrusion message followed by the "...normal.mode" not found. I opened the cabinet and found a large moth. Removed it and a lot of dust. When I attempted  a command from this site the keys on the keyboard would not respond. Hence my request. Thank you karel for your responses. Much appreciated.