# EXT4/fd (sda1): previous I/O error to superblock detected

Tags: 11.10

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit. Yesterday, my computer had some line error during boot-time, showed

```
EXT4/fd (sda1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
```

screenshot:

[image: http:/i.imgur.com/TMow5UU.jpg]

On this condition, my compie still could reached Desktop, but then, my Desktop showed a dialog window with unreadable-character.

screenshot:

[image: i.imgur.com/YmljPwk.jpg]

After that, it wouldn't show the Unity and some shortcut folders on Desktop became unknown-file-like

screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og0re.jpg]

Could any body tell me what is this and how could I get rid of it?

Comment: This could be a sign of failing disk. First thing to do now would be to **stop using the drive and backup** your important data. Then look what [S.M.A.R.T.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive) tells you for this disk and add this to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unknown reason the file system has been scrambled.
The recovery was possible, but some data has been lost.

With a little bit luck you can find some fragments of your lost files in the `lost+found` directory of the `sda1` partition.

This is the time you should:

1. Restore a backup to a different location (partition). I suggest to use also a different hard disk.
2. Compare backup and recovered data.
3. Identify recovered data which is newer as the same content in your backup and not scrambled. Add this data to your restored data.
4. Replace `sda1` with the restored partition.

If you doesn't have a backup, then this is maybe the last chance to create on of the recovered data.

#### Advice

But before further productive usage of the `sda` drive, you should ensure the integrity of the drive.
For this task have a look at the commands `smartctl` and `badblocks`.

Please read the [ubuntu community documentation for smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) carefully.

#### Note

If the partition doesn't contain important data, e.g. only the ubuntu system I suggest do reinstall the system.
But before I would also do a backup (at least the `/etc/` directories).

Comment: @h-dirk-schmitt : thank you for the answer. Aren't there  any ways to keep using the disk, at least for some periode of time? Something like command to fix it or something. I don't mind with losing data, since it's a new computer and I haven't stored important data in there yet.

Comment: @thom: if it's a new computer the drive may be healthy (check SMART!), if not you may get it replaced on warranty. In case the disk is healthy I would just reformat and reinstall **12.04** LTS as 11.10 will be at its end of life next month.

Comment: @Takkat OK then, I got it now :D I'll check it first. Thank you.. :)

Comment: see documentation link above in the updated answere