# Computer slowed down very much

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, xubuntu, hardware

I had a dualboot xubuntu/windows 7 running. Yesterday my Laptop suddenly got very slow (tried both OS, both very slow in opening applications, booting up and loading web pages).

I run the memory test which one can choose in the GRUB Menu, which said nothing wrong.

I then reinstalled Xubuntu 14.04 onto the whole drive and erased the old installations. But still Xubuntu takes ages to boot, start applications,load webpages, just like a general slowdown. Also it crashes from time to time and videos stop for a few secs every 2-3 minutes.

I really appreciate any help on this!

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T410

**Edit:** I used the disk utility to check my hardware health as recommended in the comments. I am getting something like (translated) "Harddrive is probably going to fail soon (43° C / 109° F)"

Does that mean that replacing my hard drive would probably solve all my problems?

Comment: Hard Drive failure?

Comment: @Tim Can I and how could I check for that?

Comment: [How can I check the health of my hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive)

Comment: The output of `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`would have more informations, but it sounds not really good. If you have some important data on your Hard Drive backup it. Did you have another HDD to test the system ?

Comment: If you're getting warnings about your hard drive, then it's a good idea to replace it - but from what you're described about poor performance, it wouldn't hurt to get the dust blown out of that laptop. Heat build up cripples even the best computers.

Comment: _"'Harddrive is probably going to fail soon (43° C / 109° F)' Does that mean that replacing my hard drive would probably solve all my problems?"_ Yes, sounds like your hard drive is dying. Best to backup any important data you have on there.

Comment: Your problem is not about Ubuntu, it is about a hardware device that Ubuntu actually checked and found it will eventually die soon (Something Windows lacks completely). The recommendations mentioned in the comments are very important and should actually change it.

Comment: Thanks it actually was the hard drive. Replaced it and everything back to normal now