# Why does ubuntu installer keep crashing when creating the partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to an ASUS X551MAV that had Windows 8 pre-intalled, unfortunately Windows crashed and I managed to mess it up even more, now I want to install Ubuntu, but it keeps stalling out when it's creating the partitions.  the error is that it can't create the /dev/sda2 partiton and just stalls out, is there any other way I can fix this so it will run correctly?

Comment: Do you need any data off the Hard Drive?

Comment: Don't need anything, it's for mybsin, I can always re-install his games

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is usually a hint of a hardware fault. I recommend you [run a SMART test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive) on your disk. If you need help interpreting results, post back with details. It could be there's some other fault, though -- either a disk problem that won't show up in SMART (like a cabling or controller problem) or something that's not disk-related (bad RAM, maybe).

Comment: It turns out it was a bad Hard Drive, I replaced it and no problems in the install.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rod Smith's answer, another source of problems during the installation is usually a defective Live CD / DVD. If you can boot into Ubuntu from the Live CD / DVD, check the Live CD / DVD's MD5 hash by running `md5sum <optical_drive_block_device>`, where `<optical_drive_block_device>` is the optical drive's block device as listed by `lsblk`, and check it against the MD5 hash of the image found at [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) under the name of the Ubuntu release you're trying to install.