# Quick doubts about an HDD

Tags: hard-drive, live-cd

If I'm not so wrong, my hdd is going to die. Right?

Is there anything that I can try besides switching the hdd?

If the HDD is dead how many skips on the water it is going to do? 4 or 5? /joke

(the image was when I was trying to run a live CD)

[image]

UPDATE: Now it's clicking! It is officially dead...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the health of my hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive)

Comment: Since he can't log in on the system, I don't think its a duplicate @Mark Kirby

Comment: Sure it is @kek_kek They can just use a live USB to test it.

Comment: Nop, can't do anything...

Comment: @SuaMae Boot a live USB and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your HDD without need of log in, as Mark Kirby pointed out. Just create a Live USB where you can install HDD checkers.

**Create a Live USB**

On windows I advise downloading [Rufus USB Creator](https://rufus.akeo.ie).

1- Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the 'Device' dropdown
[image]

2- Click the CD Rom icon next to the 'FreeDOS' dropdown, then find your downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click 'Open' and then 'Start'
[image]

3- Click 'Yes' when it asks to download Syslinux software
[image]

4- Click 'OK' to write in ISO Image mode
[image]

5- Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then 'OK' to continue
[image]

6- When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu
[image]

7- Plug the USB into your laptop, and boot from USB. Click on "Try Ubuntu"

**Check the HDD state**

Quoted from @Oli's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive):

> For the desktop, you can use "Disk Utility" (aka `palimpsest` or
>   `gnome-disks` depending on the Ubuntu release) for this.
>
> For the command line, I suggest you install the `smartmontools`
>   package and play around with `smartctl`. Eg:
>
> ```
> sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
> ```

Source:  [How to check the health of my hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive)  and  [How to Create a bootable usb stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Last update: Hdd is truly dead

Comment: I dont think editing the answer only with the links is a good idea, if the links gets down there no answer

Comment: @wjandrea please don't do such edits. i) removing clear instructions (even if they are specific to a single OS) and replacing them with a link makes the answer [not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/203101). ii) copying content from another answer on Ask Ubuntu is *not* plagiarism. Answers posted here are free to be copied and reused. Especially since kek_kek had included attribution.

Comment: @terdon I'm a bit conffused. Yesterday I got downvoted as hell for "plagiarism" another ask ubuntu answer, where I just checked the commands from another very old answer. What should I do then? I always try to check the links and commands for errors, but when I get downvoted for plagiarism, I feel it's not fair.

Comment: @kek_kek what? Where? And I never said you plagiarized! On the contrary, I was telling wjandrea who edited your answer that copying (with attribution) from another Ask Ubuntu answer is *not* plagiarism.

Comment: No, not you, some downvoted I got yesterday on an answer.

Comment: Ah, yes. Well, that's different. If you actually post the exact same answer as someone else, you should i) put it in a quote block and clearly state that it isn't your work or, more likely, ii) vote to close the question as a duplicate of the one whose answer you copied. I admit I hadn't realized your were copying every word from the other answer!

Comment: How can I do that quote?

Comment: @wjandrea, my point about copying stands but I hadn't realized that kek_kek had actually copied every word! That's not nice, no. Such quotes should be clearly marked by putting them in a quote block.

Comment: @kek_kek use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @terdon understood

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking it's a dead drive wih firm conviction, go for the cheaper possibility and replace the cable. If that works you saved yourself from having to buy a new drive at the expense of a fraction of the cost for a new drive.