# Ubuntu Installation: Attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 at / failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

My Windows 10 crashed a few days back and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my system as the sole OS. These are the steps I'm following:

1) Creating Bootable USB for Ubuntu with GPT partition type through rufus.exe
2) Using GParted to do manual partition before installing. The partitions that I made are

- swap area (4 GB)
- root(/) - ext4 - (20 GB)
- /home - ext4 - (20 GB)
- FAT32 partition with boot and esp flag set and size 20 GB

3) Installing Ubuntu 16.04, going through all the steps. selecting 'something else' and selecting 'install now'.

While installing always get an error

```
Attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 in SCSI0 (0,0,0). partition at / failed." or same error for /boot/efi.
```

I tried a lot but, couldn't fix the problem. My HDD is GUID Partition format and it says that "its gonna fail soon".

Please let me know if anyone has the solution to this.

Comment: Looks like your HDD is about to physically break. Verify by booting into live Ubuntu ("Try Ubuntu without installing") and follow http://askubuntu.com/q/38566/367990 to get the HDD's S.M.A.R.T. status.

Comment: I checked the status of my HDD in disk utility and it says in the assessment label "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON (30° C / 86° F)". What can I do to repair it?

Comment: Nothing. It's physically damaged. Back up all important data on it and buy a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Brought a new 1TB HDD. But even after completing the entire installation, Ubuntu wasn't booting. I check what was wrong by looking in the boot menu, my Internal HDD was listed in the Legacy boot table. So, I converted my BIOS setup from UEFI to Legacy, made my bootable USB in BIOS/MBR format and started installion.

Rather than selecting 'Something Else' and going for manual partition, I selected 'Erase disk and install' and after seven days of hard work and research, I finally got Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop.

However, I still don't know if the problem was my HDD or coz my BIOS setup was in UEFI.

But, now it works...