# Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' - dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

The mentioned error message greets me often when I start up my laptop. I have tried many methods mentioned in some answers, nothing helped.

**Facts:**

- Installed dual boot for the second time (reinstalled because of same reason) following [How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) as closely as possible.
- Following that guide I have created a ~2 GB boot-partition with flags *esp* and *boot* (**Note: the boot flag is now on the Windows-partition, I have no idea how it got there.**), then the Windows partition, followed by the swap, the 20 GB Ubuntu "/" and the remaining as "/home" partition.

  ```
  Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
   1      1049kB  2149MB  2147MB  primary   fat32           esp
   2      2149MB  378GB   376GB   primary   ntfs            boot
   3      378GB   384GB   6000MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
   4      384GB   500GB   116GB   extended
   5      384GB   404GB   20,0GB  logical   ext4
   6      404GB   500GB   96,1GB  logical   ext4
  ```
- I used boot-repair to restore grub after installing Windows (could not reach Ubuntu on my HDD, I used an USB-version). After that, for 3 days it worked well.
- Having had the dreaded error message again (no grub rescue, only "Press any key to continue"), I checked [gParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2YM7.jpg) and noticed the boot flag is on the wrong disk.
- Looking for the grub folder, I found it to be in the 20 GB "/" [partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n70j5.jpg) as it should be. On the Windows partition, however, two strange folders appeared: *Boot* and *boot-sav*. The former contains folders like *bg-BG* (languages) with *bootmgr.exe.mui* and often, but not always, *memtest.exe.mui*:

  ```
  BCD           cs-CZ  es-MX  hu-HU        nb-NO      ro-RO       tr-TR
  BCD.LOG       da-DK  et-EE  it-IT        nl-NL      ru-RU       uk-UA
  BCD.LOG1      de-DE  fi-FI  ja-JP        pl-PL      sk-SK       zh-CN
  BCD.LOG2      el-GR  Fonts  ko-KR        pt-BR      sl-SI       zh-HK
  bg-BG         en-GB  fr-CA  lt-LT        pt-PT      sr-Latn-CS  zh-TW
  BOOTSTAT.DAT  en-US  fr-FR  lv-LV        qps-ploc   sr-Latn-RS
  bootvhd.dll   es-ES  hr-HR  memtest.exe  Resources  sv-SE
  ```

The *boot-sav* is related to boot-repair, *log* and *mbr_backups* (empty) are in it.

- Using sudo fdisk -l, I got a warning: *Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.*

**My questions:**

- Could my partitioning theoretically work? (Somewhere I read the boot files should all be within the first 137 GB.)
- Should I simply change the *boot* flag back to the first, *esp* partition?
- Does having an SSHD have anything to do with my issue?
- Of course, what should I try to make my computer bootable without issues most of the time?

Other, maybe useful info from `parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA ST500LM000-1EJ16 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk uses the MBR partitioning system (called `msdos` by `parted`). Windows installs in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode on such disks, so you're almost certainly booting Windows in BIOS mode.

An EFI *can* boot from an MBR disk, and you *can* create an ESP on such a disk. In `parted`, an ESP on an MBR disk has the `esp` flag set, whereas the `boot` flag identifies a partition to which the DOS/Windows boot loader will chainload. On a GPT disk, the `boot` and `esp` flags are synonymous; they both identify an ESP. Thus, your disk has separate ESPs and Windows-bootable partitions. Chances are the output you showed is as it should be. You should *not* try to move either the `esp` or the `boot` flags.

That said, there's a good chance that your ESP is doing no good, since you've probably installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode, too. I can't be sure of that without more data, though. (The `RESULTS.txt` file generated by the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) would be helpful.)

The warning about `/dev/sda4` (your extended partition) not starting on a physical sector boundary is harmless; you can ignore it.

You haven't said what your problem is, or if you have one at all, aside from not understanding how all these pieces fit together. If you're having a problem of some sort, please specify what it is, and provide that Boot Info Script output. (Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here.)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! The pastebin link with the results of Boot Info Script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23359976/

Comment: The problem is the occasional "Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error message greeting instead of grub - sometimes with grub rescue, sometimes "press any key to continue". After that, booting again might help, but often not. I did a reinstall a week ago, since then only one such occasion occured, but I fear it will happen soon again, that's why I finally decided to ask the question. The "boot" flag moving to the Windows partition also bothered me (bullet #2), as I created the first 2 GiB partition just for the booting process (bullet #1) and now it is almost empty.

Comment: You are, as I suspected, booting in BIOS mode, so your ESP (`/dev/sda1`) is doing no good. If you're seeing occasional error messages about attempts to read or write outside of `hd0` (GRUB's name for your hard disk), then that suggests a hardware problem to me. I recommend you [run a SMART utility on your disk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive) to see if it might be likely to fail soon; and if so, replace the disk ASAP.

Comment: I got these results: https://postimg.org/image/j9x406upf/ A bit scary. Should I look for a new HDD?

Comment: Yeah, I'd replace it. For more on this error, see [here](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9119) (or do a Web search). I recommend replacing the disk ASAP; some types of disk failure can get *much* worse *very* quickly. I'm not sure this is one of those types, but I wouldn't take chances myself, especially not if the disk held important data.

Comment: Thank you once again for your help, I made sure to have fresh backup of the HDD, and replacement is already on its way.