# Booting process takes too long if I let usb drive pluged

Tags: boot

I have a new PC (Intel NUC) since 3 months. I have installed Ubuntu 18/04 LTS.

boot time used to be short (20 seconds) but since 15 days (approx) boot time takes 3 to 4 minutes.

I have noticed that this happened when my USB is plugged.
But since the beginning my USB disk was all the time plugged and it did not affect boot time.

Any suggestion to reduce the booting time?

Comment: I would check the device health. Usually this is a sign the device health get worse. If it is SATA (or IDE) attached device you can use its S.M.A.R.T. feature to check it. This feature works also for some USB devices. For this purposes read this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive

Comment: Try plugging in a different USB flash drive and test again. That would tell you if it's something specific to the UFD you are using or something else.

Comment: If the USB has the "boot" flag set it its MBR or GPT it could delay the boiot as your BIOS tries to boot from it. I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.