# Is there a permanent fix for "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY"?

Tags: boot, 18.04, initramfs

[[fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually][1])

Like mentioned in the above post, I am getting the same error and I have used the solution mentioned. But, the thing is I am getting this error repeatedly , ( I would say, at least once in every 5 starting up on average). Is there any permanent fix for this error ?  Please explain, why does this happens too. Might there be a chance , it would be some hardware error ?

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: No, I only use Ubuntu

Comment: Edit your question to include a screenshot of the `Disks` application view of the SMART Data from the drive. Also include `terminal` output of `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` (use paste.ubuntu.com if that output is large).

Answer (score 2):

Yikes - that error is not trivial. It indicates a serious problem that could result in data loss. If it is happening regularly or frequently, the way to 'permanently fix' it is to investigate further.

First, back up any data that you value and don't want to lose on to some other disk or media.

Second, [run a SMART test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/) on your hard drive.