# Speed of HDD getting extremly slow

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, hdparm

I have two hard drives in my system one `SSD` for the OS and a `HDD` for data storage. 
After a fresh restart I check the reading speed of my `HDD` via:

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdb
```

and I get quite varying results (between `15MB/s` and `200MB/s`) for it.

After I start a `python` program which performs calculations on the `HDD` the speed drops extremely (even after I stop the program).`hdparm -t /dev/sdb` stops working and is not giving any results back. 
From then on also copying files on or from the `HDD` is very slow (or not working).

I am using `ubuntu 18.04 LTS` and the `Drive Settings` show me the `HDD` is mounted by `NTFS`
I don't suspect my python code to be the problem since everything runs fine when I pull the data onto the `SSD`.

It would be very helpful if you could give me advice how to find the source of the problem here!

Comment: Do you mean **reading**  in your sentence *I check the writing speed of my HDD*?

Comment: Thanks ofc your right

Comment: I would check the HDD health! If S.M.A.R.T. option is enabled in the BIOS, you can use the GUI tool Disks to get the info of the HDD health: https://askubuntu.com/q/528072/566421 and https://askubuntu.com/q/38566/566421

Comment: Thank you for your help! The sort Self-Test runs through without a problem, I will report if the longer version yields a problem. Up to now I suspected no hardware-problem because the reading/writing speed was restored after a restart of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out the problem was most likely that the drive was format in `NTFS`. I formatted it to `EXT4` and so far no more problems.