# my external hard drive takes forever to load

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

my external hard drive takes forever to load even if it does finally load, all my data appears to be either lost or never load. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS, I can't seem to imagine a problem that might have caused this, although I have removed it multiple times and reconnected it to see whether it'll work normally again ......what should I do?

Comment: The disk can be damaged, or there is not enough power. It is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Check disk's S.M.A.R.T. data and errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the health of my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive)